# Custom prompt doesn't work on Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, prompt

I like to use a custom prompt (current path in blue) on my unix machine:

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;34m\]\w \$\[\e[m\] '
```

But when I try to use it on Mac's terminal it doesn't work: it fails to detect the end of the prompt and overwrites the prompt when I type commands. This also happens when I'm inputting a long command where it wraps over the same line instead of starting a new line.

I don't understand why this is the case since I use bash on both machines. Any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are getting different results, but the correct value should be

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;34m\]\w \$\[\e[m\] '
```

Non-printing characters should be enclosed in `\[ \]`, so that bash can compute the correct length of the prompt on the screen (for cursor-positioning purposes).

Comment: Yes, export PS1='\[\e[0;34m\]\w \$\[\e[m\] ' is the value I'm using. I somehow miscopied it in my question. It doesn't work as I explained above.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @mareks In your comment above, you again seem to be missing the backslash before the `[` and `]` that enclose the ANSI escape codes for the colors. `\[\e[`, not `[\e[`.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting it in regular double quotes ""  instead of these ' '  single quotes. Worked for me. Also works with iTerm as well as Mac OS X's terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`\[\e[` became `[\e[` in the post when it wasn't formatted as code. Sorry about the confusion. I solved the problem by updating bash from 3.0 to 4.2 on my mac.